# Scraping addresses on a county Scale w/ Python & BS4

Tags: python, json, google-maps, beautifulsoup, geocoding

Okay, so I am trying to create a 'fixture finder' website for rugby teams and players across the UK, I am currently attempting to implement a web scraper using python and Beautifulsoup in order to scrape google for the addresses, to then be geocoded and inserted into the database as a long & lat for the maps API to map it out for the user.

My question is, is there a way in which I could simply use the google geocoder API to retrieve the long & lat of ALL the clubs in that specific county and then parse through BeautifulSoup to retrieve the long and lat off of the generated page (and then just rinse and repeat for all the counties in the UK) following the example on: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder/1.8.0#downloads
but on a county scale

OR if someone could shed some light into potentially scraping the listings off of google maps, as I'm getting a general feeling that maps isn't allowed to be scraped.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: if you use API then you get results as JSON (not HTML) which you can easily convert to Python's directory using module `json`. To get data from server you need module like `urllib` or `requests` - with `requests` you can use `response.json()` and you get JSON data already converted to dictionary. There should be even python module to work with google APIs.

Comment: If you havet to get points from google map without using API then map uses JavaScript code which create "Markers" on map - and you can try to find string "Marker" in JavaScript code to find lat, long. See example Javascript's code in Google documentation: [Google Maps APIs - Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Comment: `geocoder` from your link can convert addresses to `lat,long` only if you already have rugby teams' addresses. Problem is to find those addresses. You can search in `Google Search` or maybe on other portals with sport news.

Comment: @furas thanks for the response! I think possibly scraping data from the maps 'markers' is what I'm probably going to opt for. for example. input the county > retrieve data sets of markers > store the long/lat from markers into the database. I am just struggling to find the 'marker' information in the HTML at the moment

Comment: If you will use API then you will get all as JSON data which you can convert easily to Python's dictionary and you don't have to search in HTML (you don't need `BS4`)

Comment: see [google-maps-services-python](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) - probably "Places API" should do what you need. You have to only go to Google Developers pages and get "key" to works with API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Python Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) and this code I got names and locations (and more) for query `'Rugby Club, London'`

You will have to create own project on [developers.google.com/console](https://developers.google.com/console), activate `Places API for Web Service` (there  is no version for `Desktop Application`) and get credencial for `PlacesAPI` - it gives you own `key=` (API key).

Current `key=` is active so you can test code, but I will deactivate it later.

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='AIzaSyBiC8vKEEF-MLP9a2de0PLs-S_XrEL0kSQ')

results = gmaps.places('Rugby Club, London')

for key in item.keys():
    print('key:', key)

print('-----')

for item in results['results']:
    print('name:', item['name'])
    print('lat:', item['geometry']['location']['lat'])
    print('lng:', item['geometry']['location']['lng'])
    print('location:', item['geometry']['location'])
    print('---')

print('-----')

#for item in results['results'][:1]:
#    for key, value in item.items():
#        print(key, ':', value)
```

Result: (available keys and some names and locations)

```
key: formatted_address
key: geometry
key: icon
key: id
key: name
key: opening_hours
key: photos
key: place_id
key: rating
key: reference
key: types
-----
name: East London Rugby Football Club
lat: 51.5291765
lng: 0.0102242
location: {'lat': 51.5291765, 'lng': 0.0102242}
---
name: Hampstead Rugby Football Club
lat: 51.5571358
lng: -0.1555037
location: {'lat': 51.5571358, 'lng': -0.1555037}
---
name: Chiswick Rugby Club
lat: 51.47323
lng: -0.256633
location: {'lat': 51.47323, 'lng': -0.256633}
---
name: Wimbledon Rugby Football Club
lat: 51.41975009999999
lng: -0.2464434
location: {'lat': 51.41975009999999, 'lng': -0.2464434}
---
name: Saracens Amateur RFC
lat: 51.64230209999999
lng: -0.1429848
location: {'lat': 51.64230209999999, 'lng': -0.1429848}
---
name: Kilburn Cosmos RFC
lat: 51.55542000000001
lng: -0.2297043000000001
location: {'lat': 51.55542000000001, 'lng': -0.2297043000000001}
---
name: Barnes Rugby Football Club
lat: 51.47568860000001
lng: -0.2373847
location: {'lat': 51.47568860000001, 'lng': -0.2373847}
---
name: Southwark Tigers Rugby Club
lat: 51.4839377
lng: -0.07720149999999999
location: {'lat': 51.4839377, 'lng': -0.07720149999999999}
---
name: HACKNEY RFC
lat: 51.5732467
lng: -0.0611062
location: {'lat': 51.5732467, 'lng': -0.0611062}
---
name: UCS Old Boys Rugby Club
lat: 51.5575127
lng: -0.2022654
location: {'lat': 51.5575127, 'lng': -0.2022654}
---
name: Millwall Rugby Club
lat: 51.487884
lng: -0.010493
location: {'lat': 51.487884, 'lng': -0.010493}
---
name: Haringey Rhinos RFC
lat: 51.604738
lng: -0.099553
location: {'lat': 51.604738, 'lng': -0.099553}
---
name: Finchley RFC
lat: 51.6067705
lng: -0.1698911
location: {'lat': 51.6067705, 'lng': -0.1698911}
---
name: Trailfinders Rugby Club
lat: 51.520878
lng: -0.306115
location: {'lat': 51.520878, 'lng': -0.306115}
---
name: Old Ruts Rugby Club
lat: 51.4079431
lng: -0.1993505
location: {'lat': 51.4079431, 'lng': -0.1993505}
---
name: Ealing Trailfinders Rugby Club
lat: 51.524832
lng: -0.3293849999999999
location: {'lat': 51.524832, 'lng': -0.3293849999999999}
---
name: Chingford Rugby Football Club
lat: 51.6301123
lng: -0.0171661
location: {'lat': 51.6301123, 'lng': -0.0171661}
---
name: Old Elthamians RFC Senior Rugby
lat: 51.43445149999999
lng: 0.0296538
location: {'lat': 51.43445149999999, 'lng': 0.0296538}
---
name: Eton Manor RFC
lat: 51.579528
lng: 0.03874
location: {'lat': 51.579528, 'lng': 0.03874}
---
name: London Skolars Rugby League Club
lat: 51.60465900000001
lng: -0.100032
location: {'lat': 51.60465900000001, 'lng': -0.100032}
---
```